# Can service dogs be kept indoors?

Tags: dogs

Dogs are "haram" to be kept (except as hearding or guard dogs) and are not allowed in one's home.
But what about dogs trained to help disabled people(blind,hearing impairment,seizures......)?
They need to be close to their owner and living with them in order to be of help.
Could those dogs be kept indoors?
Sunni point of  view please but would like to know about others as well.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, dogs should be avoided because their saliva is impure but trained dogs for helping disabled/blind  people are allowed because that is a necessity. However, they should be taught to not lick their owner.

This is the mainstream Sunni point of view.

Comment: Any source for the "saliva" is impure part? Its saliva similar to human saliva. I don't see the difference.

Comment: @masfenix The Saliva is impure but should be avoided is not Islamic, if you are willing to wash it, I have a similar answer here that explains it more: http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/24322/12537